# Pandas string encoding when retrieving cell value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, string

I have the following Series:

```
s = pd.Series(['ANO DE LOS BÃEZ MH EE 3 201'])
```

When I print the series I get:

```
0    ANO DE LOS BÃEZ MH EE 3 201
```

But when I get the cell element I get an hexadecimal value in the string:

```
>>> s.iloc[0]
'ANO DE LOS BÃ\x81EZ MH EE 3 201'
```

Why does this happens and how can I retrieve the cell value and get the string: `'ANO DE LOS BÃEZ MH EE 3 201'`?

Comment: I don't thinks its a python issue, does your terminal support unicode?

Comment: Well I can define and manipulate the string I posted without problems in the Python REPL. Only when using Pandas I have this problem.

Comment: Okay, maybe my guess is wrong ...
however I tested your snippets on my machine with python and ipython (3.8.2) and pandas 0.25.3 and its works fine, but I guess thats not very helpful to you

Comment: Thank for the reply. Your comment actually helped me. When copying the string from stack overflow I didn't se the problem just like you. The problem just appears with the original string which I got from sentry

Answer (score 0):

Even though I am not really sure where the issue arised I Could solve it by using the [unidecode](https://github.com/avian2/unidecode) package.

```
output_string = unidecode(s.iloc[0])
```